# pg-promise task double connection?

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

According to [Chaining-Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries) pg-promise wiki Task is a preferred way for making multiple queries within single shared connection.

While I understand that there is no sense to use Task for a single query, I used single query for a test just to see how it seen in logs. Obtained results somehow wondered me

Without Task:

```
07:14:02 connect(user@db); useCount: 0
07:14:02 SELECT * FROM t
07:14:02 disconnect(user@db)
```

With Task:

```
07:15:27 connect(user@db); useCount: 0
07:15:27 task/start
07:15:27 connect(user@db); useCount: 0
07:15:27 SELECT * FROM t
07:15:27 disconnect(user@db)
07:15:27 task/end; duration: .009, success: true
07:15:27 disconnect(user@db)
```

`useCount: 0` means fresh physically allocated connection

Making several such queries in a row repeat the pattern. Each Task wrapped query shows 2 allocated connections. One for main (?) thread and second for Task itself.

`useCount` correctly being increased, meaning that connections are reused from pool. But main thing remains - each Task processing allocates 2 connections from connections pool.

Does it expected behavior or I'm missing smth?

Comment: You need to show the code the creates this log. Looks like you are enforcing creation of a new connection while inside the task, and most likely because you are not using the connection context provided by the task.

Comment: @vitaly-t   You are right. In straightforward case all works within single connection
In my case callback method was pasted as a parameter. Within it there is also was another wrapper that was dynamically selecting corresponding entity repository (aka pg-promise-demo). In such pattern ctx was lost and child queries were allocating new connection from the pool

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to post this as response to @vitaly-t comment because of size.

In order to have child queries re-use parent session context make sure you call context object **t** provided inside the task method

```
return this.db.task(t => {
  return t.any('select now()').then(
    () => t.any('select now()').then(
      () => '2 queries are executed'
    )
  )
})
```

and we get

```
13:30:26 connect(user@db); useCount: 0
13:30:26 task/start
13:30:26 task: select now()
13:30:26 task: select now()
13:30:26 task/end; duration: .005, success: true
13:30:26 disconnect(user@db)
```

Comment: That's what [documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries) has always told you to do ;)